# Can we update a record in a table and simultaneously insert the updated record in another table in Oracle DB 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to write a query that will check for a condition in table A and updates all the records that matches the condition in table A and then take those updated records only and insert them as new records in table B. Table A and Table B both has the same structure.
I tried doing this with Merge statement, but it only satisfies first half of my requirement, that is updating the records.
Please help !

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/returninginto_clause.htm#LNPLS01354 may help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Go through the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and read it carefully to get an understanding of how to ask a good question on this site. Additionally, for a question specific to Oracle/SQL, it is important that you add sample data and expected result and the query that you tried / errors you got if any. Read to know what's an mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1):

One option to do that might be a database trigger - something very similar to *auditing* changes you make to a table. For example (based on Scott's schema):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> create table dept_audit as select * from dept where 1 = 2;

Table created.

SQL> alter table dept_audit add datum date;

Table altered.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bu_dept
  2    after update on dept
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into dept_audit (deptno, dname, loc, datum)
  6      values (:new.deptno, :new.dname, :new.loc, sysdate);
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.

SQL> update dept set loc = 'Dallas' where deptno = 20;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from dept_audit;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC           DATUM
---------- -------------- ------------- -------------------
        20 RESEARCH       Dallas        05.11.2018 08:19:06

SQL>
```

So, you'd only `UPDATE` rows you want; trigger would "copy" them into another table. This isn't strictly "one query" you mentioned in a question, but - hopefully - will serve the purpose.